# NonlinearModelFit error: the function value is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {101} at {a,k,m0} = \ {1.,1.,1.}

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

So I'm trying to find a sigmoidal fit for my numerical solutions of these two ODEs but I keep getting an error and I don't know how to get around it. Here's my code:

```
    x = Clip[r[t], {0, 1}];
    y = Clip[rpp[t], {0, 1}];
tdata = NDSolve[{r'[t] == -L1*rpp[t] + c, 
 rpp'[t] == L2*rpp[t] (1 - (rpp[t]/(r[t] + rpp[t]))) + L3*r[t], 
 r[0] == 1, rpp[0] == 0} /. {L1 -> 0.5, c -> 0.001, L2 -> 0.91, 
 L3 -> 0.05}, {r[t], rpp[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 0];
edata = Flatten[
Table[{t, RandomReal[{0.98, 1.02}] x, 
  RandomReal[{0.98, 1.02}] y} /. tdata, {t, 0, 10, 0.1}], 1];
 ListPlot[edata[[All, {1, 3}]], AxesLabel -> {t, rpp}]
 ListPlot[edata[[All, {1, 2}]], AxesLabel -> {t, r}]
 fitr = NonlinearModelFit[edata[[All, {1, 3}]], 
 a/(1 + e^(k (m + m0))), {a, k, m0}, m]
```

and here's the error:

```
The function value {0.` +1./(1. +e^1.),-0.005288685506835929`+1./(1. \
+e^1.1),-0.0109042799127727`+1./(1. \
+e^1.2),-0.01748650389211446`+1./(1. \
+e^1.3),-0.024352385235797344`+1./(1. \
+e^1.4),-0.03231663391095662`+1./(1. \
+e^1.5),-0.03958041357122825`+1./(1. \
+e^1.6),<<37>>,-0.8780465342218058`+1./(1. \
+e^5.4),-0.8918669583936019`+1./(1. \
+e^5.5),-0.8976928755882382`+1./(1. \
+e^5.6),-0.9265792283447786`+1./(1. \
+e^5.7),-0.9267100472622336`+1./(1. \
+e^5.8),-0.8901487868184963`+1./(1. +e^5.9),<<51>>} is not a list of \
real numbers with dimensions {101} at {a,k,m0} = {1.`,1.`,1.`}. >>
```

Why is it producing nonreals? How do I go around this?

Comment: `e` is not the number you think it is ;) In _Mathematica_, all built-ins start with a capital letter. Try `E^(k (m + m0)))` or `Exp[k (m + m0))]` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `e` in the non-linear fit should be `Exp[]` or it needs to be a variable

```
x = Clip[r[t], {0, 1}];
y = Clip[rpp[t], {0, 1}];
tdata = NDSolve[{r'[t] == -L1*rpp[t] + c, 
     rpp'[t] == L2*rpp[t] (1 - (rpp[t]/(r[t] + rpp[t]))) + L3*r[t], 
     r[0] == 1, rpp[0] == 0} /. {L1 -> 0.5, c -> 0.001, L2 -> 0.91, 
     L3 -> 0.05}, {r[t], rpp[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 0];
edata = Flatten[
   Table[{t, RandomReal[{0.98, 1.02}] x, 
      RandomReal[{0.98, 1.02}] y} /. tdata, {t, 0, 10, 0.1}], 1];
ListPlot[edata[[All, {1, 3}]], AxesLabel -> {t, rpp}]
ListPlot[edata[[All, {1, 2}]], AxesLabel -> {t, r}]
fitr = NonlinearModelFit[edata[[All, {1, 3}]], 
  a/(1 + Exp[(k (m + m0))]), {a, k, m0}, m]
```

Result:

```
0.8198795468165254/(1 + Exp[-1.6389907155528805*(-2.54832322174611 + m)])
```